# how to using JExcelApi for reading and writing excel file in android app

Tags: android

i downloaded JExcelApi for reading and writing excel file in android app. how can i import it to my eclipse or android sdk or anything before can import that to my code like this:

```
import jxl.*;
```

excuse me for my poor english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the jar File to your Project Folder into the Folder "libs". (Create it if it does not exist).
Then open the project properties in Eclipse and go to Java Build Path Libraries. Click 'Add Jar' and select the jar in the libs folder.